# Where to set number of Vusers (threads) running per process in Load Runner Controller?

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

In `Load Runner` help center is said about ["Running a Vuser as a Process or Thread"](http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/120550_c_rts_multithreading.htm):

> Alternatively, if you run each Vuser as a thread, the Controller
>   launches only one instance of the driver program (such as mdrv.exe),
>   for every 50 Vusers (by default).

How to change quantity of Vusers that run per one instance of the driver program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change maximum number of threads running per process you need to:

1. Go to LoadRunner installation folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LoadRunner\dat\protocols`
2. Find `.lrp` file that is corresponding to the protocol you use to create VuGen Script. In my case it was `Java_protocols.lrp` file for the protocol `Java Record Replay`.
3. Edit it: paste `MaxThreadPerProcess=10` after `[Vugen]`. Or edit this variable if it already exists.
4. `HP LoadRunner Controller` should be restarted so that changes could take effect.

You need to find the best ratio Vusers(Threads)/Process to use resources of your test machine the best way. From my experiments I've found that one `mdrv.exe` process can efficiently work with usage not more than 600-700MB of RAM.

N.B.: VuGen script should be set to run Vuser as a thread.